# How to make global variables in android?

Tags: global-variables

After google i found three ways:
1. static variables 
2. extending Application and using getApplicationContext
3. SharedPreferences

Comment: So you seem having the solution already. Where is your problem? Or you just want a general discussion?

Comment: oh sry :P i wanted to know the prons and cons of each way. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: read comments pls, i don't want to delete it, because it may help other who fell into the same trap...

Be careful with static variables!! I wrote an app which uses them, but on some devices it works, on some it doesn't. the problem is, if one activity edits that variable, finishes and the focus returns to another activity, the changes are not recognized. i haven't found a solution for this and somehow  i don't get it working with getApplicationContext either...

Usually i would say that i made a mistake, but in both cases, it is working on an SGSII with Android 4.0.4 but it isn't on SGSIII with 4.1... :(

So as a consequence i assume that they've changed the use of global variables, maybe out of security reasons, so that every activity gets an own instance of that variable or so, i have no idea

Comment: Activities come and go as the system needs them. Have you tried storing a variable and related code in a `Service`?

Comment: oh my god. that's really unbelievable. i found my mistake... -.- Appearantly my activity RESTARTS even though i just resume from the other activity... unbelievable... but only on the SGSIII device.  Why would the developers of android sdk implement that?! i'm really sorry for giving you wrong information

Comment: An activity may or may not be in memory at any time from what I understand... Services are for longrunning processes: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html Maybe a BroadcastReceiver for when a variable is changed, could work in your scenario?

Comment: @timothy3001 Thanks for that info. I am using static variables right now ... but i'll change it soon :)

Comment: thanks, i've a solution now. i just check in the oncreate method if that static variable is null. if so, it fills it, otherwise it just goes on. that works like a charm. and i also overwrote the finish() method in which i set that global variable to null, because it could be, that if you press the home button or so, the variable is still available and that's something i don't want in my case...